# Ask for an example showing how immutability contributes to Scala's concurrency mechanism

Tags: scala, concurrency

The following example shows that one can use a mutable variable as message sended to an **Actor**. Does Scala Actor process mutable messages and immutable messages differently? If not, why people say that immutability is the reason that Scala is good for concurrency?

```
import scala.io._
import scala.actors._
import Actor._

def getPageSize(url : String) = Source.fromURL(url).mkString.length

var abc = "http://www.verycd.com"

def getPageSizeConcurrently() = {
  abc = "http://www.twitter.com"  // changing value

  val caller = self
  actor { caller ! (abc, getPageSize(abc)) }
  receive {
    case (url, size) =>
      println("Size for " + url + ": " + size)            
  }
}

getPageSizeConcurrently
```

**Update**: I got a very nice reply at [here](http://scala-forum.org/read.php?3,941,942#msg-942).

Comment: Why is `abc` defined outside the function where it is used ? Will the `getPageSizeConcurrently` method be called by several threads concurrently ?

Comment: @paradigmatic This is only an artifact example, not real code in a project.

Comment: Of course, but it's very difficult to comment on the snippet your provided, because it is very artificial. In this example, `abc` should be defined inside the only function using it... If other functions can read/modify it, then a concurrency issue *may* arise. But to answer you correctly, you should provide the other possible interactions.

Comment: @paradigmatic I know it is a very dangerous manner of using Actor. I just wonder how Scala cope with it. Why doesn't Scala even give a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is a little strange, maybe you are wondering why Scala still has mutable variable / data structure if immutable one is better for concurrency?

Yes, immutability is good for concurrency and is easier to reason about your code just as others answered.

But that does not mean mutable is useless or inherently bad, sometimes implementation using mutable `var` or data structure is  easier or maybe running faster in some specific case.

Scala **does not force you doing everything imutable** like Haskell, instead it **provide and encourage** you use immutable `val` and data structures.

But it **also provide you mutable ones**, make sure it is there if you really need it.

So, yes. Scala/Akka actor will process mutable messages the same as immutable ones, but you should not do it if you didn't have a good reason.

And if you're using `var`, you should have a good reason too, and should limit their scop.

Answer (score 3):

The way you've framed your question is, as other have pointed out, making answering it a bit difficult.  Perhaps it's because you've focused on Actors, and the example you've cooked up is a bit odd.

The bottom line is that Scala, along with its Actor implementation, as well as the Akka implementation of Actors, will happily let you shoot yourself in head with mutability.  That seems to be the core question you're asking, so if that's all you wanted, you can stop reading now :)

Immutability, however, *does* improve the quality of your concurrent programs in a number of ways, and Scala's marriage of mutability with immutability with OO and Functional programming provides you with a lot of flexibility in how you implement things.

What people don't seem to say is that the notion of programming immutably requires *a different style of programming* than most imperative programmers are used to (I certainly wasn't used to it when I started learning it).  Many seem to think that they can code the way they always did, replace their mutable objects with immutable ones, and collect the profit.  Not so.

If we take `List` as an example (the seemingly ubiquitous example, in fact), we can see how one might write some code to use it.

I'm going to use Akka's Future implementation and do some really silly stuff with `List`s of Ints.  The algorithm isn't all that important.  What's important is to recognize what's *not* there - concurrency protection.  I don't need to even *think* about problems with concurrent access because it's entirely immutable.  I added the type annotations below in order to make it clear what's happening - Scala would actually infer it all.

```
import akka.dispatch.{ExecutionContext, Future, Await}
import akka.util.duration._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

object Main {
  val execService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
  implicit val execContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(execService)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // A Future list of 1's
    val flist: Future[List[Int]] = Future { (1 to 5) map { _: Int => 1 } toList }

    // The goal is to create a new list of Ints in 25 "iterations" across
    // multiple threads
    val result: Future[List[Int]] = (1 to 5).foldLeft(flist) { (acc, _) =>

      // "Loop" 5 times, creating 5 new lists of Ints, but these 'new' lists
      // share most of their content with the previous list
      val fs: IndexedSeq[Future[List[Int]]] = (1 to 5) map { i =>
        acc map { numlist =>
          (i * numlist.sum) :: numlist
        }
      }

      // Reduce the 5 lists we just created back down to one list again, by 
      // performing a pairwise sum across them all... in the Future
      Future.reduce(fs) { (a, l) =>
        (a zip l) map { case (i, j) => i + j }
      }
    }

    // Wait for the concurrency to complete and print out the final list
    println(Await.result(result, 1 second))

    // Shut down the execution system that was running our stuff concurrently
    execContext.shutdown()
  }
}
// Prints: List(12000000, 3000000, 750000, 187500, 46875, 3125, 3125, 3125, 3125, 3125)
```

The intermediate lists that are created with `(i * numlist.sum) :: numlist` all use bits from `numlist`.  The 5 new lists that come out of that loop are actually created as 5 new values that have pointers into `numlist`, not 5 whole new lists.  i.e. `list1 = "newvalue" + oldlist` and `list2 = "another new value" + oldlist`, etc...

Programming immutably implies the model of transformation.  Take a data structure, give it to something, it transforms it and passes it to someone else, and so on.  It can be *way* faster and more reliable that mutable programming, and it can also be slower, depending on what you're doing, but the bottom line, as @mhs stated, is that it's easier to reason about in terms of safety.

It's not obvious how this maps to your usual mode of imperative programming because, in general, it doesn't.  And that's also why it doesn't make immediate sense to you.  It's like anything else in coding - it takes time to gain a true understanding of a new paradigm.

Comment: So Scala's Actor borrowed the concept and syntax from Erlang, but it does provide the same guaranty of concurrency safty? That's disappointing to me because that means `val` is no different to java's `final` except for being shorter.

Comment: `val` and `final` are not the same... they share some of the same qualities but are not the same.  But that isn't relevant to your initial question... you wanted to know how Scala's immutability helps concurrency, not whether Scala enforces immutability.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have used "enforce" but not "help". I (wrongly) thought that scala's actor will treat immutable messages more aggressively than treating mutable ones. So I used "help", meant to referring to the difference. Anyway, this answer is definitely very valuable for those who walk in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Immutability facilitates reasoning about the correctness of concurrent programs. Assuming that all objects you share between actors are immutable, you can safely keep assumptions about them without knowing anything about what the other actors - who might be implemented by third parties - actually do. For example, if you know that you've instantiated an immutable list with ten objects whose `f` fields all contain positive values, then you can safely continue working with this assumption even if you share the list with others, and you won't run into the situation where your code relies on the assumption that there still are ten elements with positive `f` fields in the list, but it is actually the case that another actor modified the list such that it contains only a single element with a negative `f` field.

Immutability makes reasoning about programs much easier in general, that is, also in the sequential case. This is one reason why proving the correctness of Haskell programs is much easier than proving the correctness of Java or C#. For the latter one needs specialised logics such as [Separation Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_logic) or [Implicit Dynamic Frames](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~jan.smans/ecoop09.pdf) who enable you to reason about shared mutable state. If you are interested, have a look at [VeriFast](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.jacobs/verifast/)(for SL) and Chalice ([project page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chalice/) and [web interface](http://rise4fun.com/Chalice), for IDF), both of which are experimental verifiers for programs involving mutable data structures and aliasing. Be warned though, that this is a field of ongoing research, these verifiers are usually not able to handle real-world programs.

Bottom line is: if you know that your data is immutable then it doesn't matter who else you give it to, they'll never be able to modify it and break your working assumptions.

Comment: You mean that Scala actor will process mutable messages the same as immutable ones, and leave the possibility of errors caused by contention there?

Comment: If actors expect messages with mutable objects, you of course can't just send them immutable ones. In this case you'd have to create a mutable version of your immutable data structure, e.g., by eagerly or lazily cloning it. The decision to work with immutable data structures usually has to be made up front when designing a module (by which I mean a set of components that cooperate, e.g., classes or actors). Another common pattern is that you module-internally work with mutable data, but you only give immutable view to 3d party components.

Comment: So using mutable objects as messages is ALLOWED, though doing that will lost all advantages of immutability stated in the answer, and is HIGHLY ERROR-PRONING since nowhere can the programmer tell the build-in actor (like the one in the question) "your message is mutable, you may need to lock it before use it". Is that the case?

Comment: In Scala, sending a message between actors means sharing data via references, not copying it. The latter would make the data actor-local, in which case modifications performed by one actor won't violate assumptions another actor has. However, copying data can be very expensive (and might entail additional communication overhead if you want to synchronise on changes), which is why it is not the default behaviour of Scala actors. And yes, it is difficult to decide whether locking of mutable data is actually necessary if you only have local information about your system.